# why are my dots rendering outside my oval circle?

Tags: html, css

I am making these two shapes with dots within them. One is a rectangle, the other a circle. Within these shapes I have made some dots, and I want these dots to render within and relative to the shapes. I cannot figure out why the dots inside the circle are outside instead. And how do I make them closer together vertically, and yet act relative to the shapes?

The purpose is to use input from the user where they decide the width and height of the shapes, and for the dots closer to the middle inside each shape.

JSFiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/kqgv6m94/1/

```css
.rectangle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
}


.oval {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.bolt:before,
.bolt:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  top: 0px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center, red 5px, transparent 5px), radial-gradient(circle at center, black 5px, transparent 5px);
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-position: top center, bottom center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.bolt:before {
  left: 0px;
}

.bolt:after {
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="rectangle" class="rectangle">
  <div>
    <div class="bolt">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div>
  <div id="oval" class="oval">
    <div class="bolt">

    </div>
  </div>
```

I tried to use flexbox, but to no avail.
I then tried to create the dots in their own containers in hopes of inheriting properties.
I also tried to 'force' the dots into place, but if I change window size / new height and weight values I get new dot-positions.

Comment: Why are you positioning the "dots" within the outer shape for the `#rectangle` but within the inner shape (`.bolt`) for the `#oval`?

Comment: sorry aboyt, that David. Pure mistake. I have changed it. I created one at a time, and it snowballed from there

Comment: No apologies necessary, I was just trying to work out if there was a reason it was, or had to be, structured that way, "*...it snowballed from there*" - as is so often the case! :)

Comment: So what's happening is that the .oval div, is still seen as a square from the browser. Therefor position the dots inside the size of the div, as it where a square. You'll probably have to create a seperate css rule for the oval's dots, using ´.oval>.bolt:before,
.oval>.bolt:after´

Comment: As the user is choosing the width and height you will probably need to do some calculation to decide where to place the dots. And what is the algorithm for placing the dots?

Comment: Anders: I tried this now, didn't really do anything.

A Haworth: The dots should just act accordingly to the cirlce and the rectangle, the cordinates are only to shape those shapes

Comment: For those answering, I would personally like the answer not only to explain *why* the dots are where they are, but also offer a solution in which the dots will be placed on/inside the perimeter of the visible shape (whether cuboid, circular, elliptic, triangular...); ideally with options for customisation for where the dots are placed (inside, outside, or on the perimeter), and options for the dots themselves in relation to the width/height of the shape.

Comment: @DavidThomas that would be out of the scope of the question imo. Also, if you want the solution to solve many different shapes, I don't think CSS alone would suffice, will a JS addition be fine?

Comment: @Damzaky, it may be out of the scope of the original question, but that's still the basis on which the bounty will be offered/satisfied. The use of JavaScript is non-ideal, though I accept it may be necessary. I think it *may* be possible using CSS trigonometric functions (`sin()`, `cos()`, `tan()`...), but I'm not likely to have enough time to investigate that possibility in the next week or so (hence the bounty being offered). As to whether JavaScript is acceptable to OP, I obviously can't answer on their behalf, but I'd prefer not to use it if at all possible.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming that the ellipse is just a stretched circle, the largest rectangle that could be inscribed inside it is `a√2 × b√2` where `a` and `b` are the lengths of semi-axes ([ref](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210695/how-to-find-the-largest-rectangle-inside-an-ellipse)).

Following is a pure CSS solution with no hard coding:

```css
.oval {
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
/* tests */
.oval-1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
.oval-2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}
.oval-3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
/* largest rectangle inside the ellipse */
.oval::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  /* center the div */
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /* use the formula, or just use 70.7106781187% xD */
  width: calc(50% * 1.4142135623730951);
  height: calc(50% * 1.4142135623730951);
  /* add the dots */
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(closest-side at center, #F00 100%, transparent 100%),
    radial-gradient(closest-side at center, #F00 100%, transparent 100%),
    radial-gradient(closest-side at center, #000 100%, transparent 100%),
    radial-gradient(closest-side at center, #000 100%, transparent 100%);
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-position:
    top left,
    top right,
    bottom left,
    bottom right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="oval oval-1"></div>
<div class="oval oval-2"></div>
<div class="oval oval-3"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

While the `.oval` is rounded, it's box is still the same rectangle as the `.rectangle` has.

If you want your dots be inside the circle, make `.bolt` be a smaller rectangle in that circle

```css
.shape {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
  
  display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.bolt {
  outline: 3px solid blue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.oval > .bolt {
  /* choose your numbers */
  height: 75%;
  width: 75%;
}

.rectangle {}

.oval {
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.bolt:before,
.bolt:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  top: 0px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center, red 5px, transparent 5px), radial-gradient(circle at center, black 5px, transparent 5px);
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-position: top center, bottom center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.bolt:before {
  left: 0px;
}

.bolt:after {
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
width: <input type="range" max="400" calue="200" oninput="document.querySelectorAll('.shape').forEach(e=>e.style.width = event.target.value+'px')">
height: <input type="range" max="200" value="100" oninput="document.querySelectorAll('.shape').forEach(e=>e.style.height = event.target.value+'px')">
<hr>
<div class="shape rectangle">
  <div class="bolt"> </div>
</div> 
<hr>
<div class="shape oval">
  <div class="bolt"> </div>
</div>
<hr>
```

Answer (score 2):

After reading David Thomas' [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76198828/why-are-my-dots-rendering-outside-my-oval-circle#comment134376221_76198828) requesting additional parameters for a bounty, I decided to create another answer in an attempt to satisfy the requests. I tried for quite a while but couldn't get accurate results and gave up.

Then I looked at the other answers again and saw the information that I needed for better accuracy and consistency in Salman A's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76222536/21849374). Therefore, my modified answer is technically a modification of Salman A's answer.

- uses variables to set the size and position of the dots according to the given width and height of the shape
- uses `clamp()` to set the min and max size of the dots

In this demonstration, I create a triangle using CSS `clip-path`. However, this clips the dots as well.

In production, I suspect a script would create the shape from the user's input, and graphics would be used for shapes other than a rectangle or ellipse. I started to write JavaScript to emulate this, but now it's way past bedtime. When editing later, I decided this example is sufficient for proof-of-concept.

```css
.shape {
  --width: 200;
  --height: 100;
  --dot-size: clamp(10px, calc( var(--width) * var(--height) * .0005px), 40px);
  width: calc( var(--width) * 1px);
  height: calc( var(--height) * 1px);
  background: gray;
}

.shape::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  translate: -50% -50%;
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(closest-side at center, red 100%, transparent 0),
    radial-gradient(closest-side at center, red 100%, transparent 0),
    radial-gradient(closest-side at center, black 100%, transparent 0),
    radial-gradient(closest-side at center, black 100%, transparent 0);
  background-size: var(--dot-size) var(--dot-size);
  background-position: top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


.shape.rectangle.inside::after {
  width: 67%;
  height: calc( 100% - var(--dot-size) );
}

.shape.rectangle.edge::after {
  width: 67%;
  height: calc( 100% + var(--dot-size) );
}

.shape.rectangle.outside::after {
  width: 67%;
  height: calc( 100% + var(--dot-size) * 3 );
}

.shape.rectangle.outside {
  margin-block: calc( var(--dot-size) * 2 );
}


.ellipse {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.shape.ellipse.inside::after {
  width: 70.7106781187%; /* 50% square root of 2 */
  height: 70.7106781187%; /* 50% square root of 2 */
}

.shape.ellipse.edge::after {
  width: calc( 70.7106781187% + var(--dot-size) );
  height: calc( 70.7106781187% + var(--dot-size) );
}

.shape.ellipse.outside::after {
  width: calc( 70.7106781187% + var(--dot-size) * 2 );
  height: calc( 70.7106781187% + var(--dot-size) * 2 );
}



.triangle {
  clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 50% 0, 100% 100%);
}

.shape.triangle.inside::after {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  translate: -50% calc( var(--dot-size) * -.1 );
}

.shape.triangle.edge::after {
  width: calc( 50% + var(--dot-size) );
  height: calc( 50% + var(--dot-size) );
  translate: -50% calc( var(--dot-size) * -.5 );
}

.shape.triangle.outside::after {
  width: calc( 50% + var(--dot-size) * 2 );
  height: calc( 50% + var(--dot-size) * 2 );
  translate: -50% calc( var(--dot-size) * -.75 );
}


/* Just for the demonstration */
div.dimen {
  text-align: center;
  width: fit-content;
}

input[type="range"] {width: 196px}

datalist {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  width: 200px;
}

p {margin-block-start: 2em}
```

```html
<!-- Just for the demonstration -->
<div class="dimen">
  Adjust the width<br>
  <input type="range" min="100" max="400" step="100" list="width" value="200" oninput="document.querySelectorAll('.shape').forEach(e=>e.style.setProperty('--width', event.target.value))">
  <datalist id="width">
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="200">200</option>
    <option value="300">300</option>
    <option value="400">400</option>
  </datalist>

  <br>Adjust the height<br>
  <input type="range" min="100" max="400" step="100" list="height" value="100" oninput="document.querySelectorAll('.shape').forEach(e=>e.style.setProperty('--height', event.target.value))">
  <datalist id="height">
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="200">200</option>
    <option value="300">300</option>
    <option value="400">400</option>
  </datalist>
</div>
<!-- Just for the demonstration -->


<p>Rectangle with dots inside</p>
<div class="shape rectangle inside"></div>

<p>Rectangle with dots on edge</p>
<div class="shape rectangle edge"></div>

<p>Rectangle with dots outside</p>
<div class="shape rectangle outside"></div>

<hr>

<p>Ellipse with dots inside</p>
<div class="shape ellipse inside"></div>

<p>Ellipse with dots on edge</p>
<div class="shape ellipse edge"></div>

<p>Ellipse with dots outside</p>
<div class="shape ellipse outside"></div>

<hr>

<p>Triangle with dots inside</p>
<div class="shape triangle inside"></div>

<p>Triangle with dots on edge</p>
<div class="shape triangle edge"></div>

<p>Triangle with dots on outside</p>
<div class="shape triangle outside"></div>
```

Comment: "*...but now it's way past bedtime.*" - so many of my potential answers go that way, and my sincere thanks for submitting this answer :) The only "issue" (constructive criticism/curiosity?) is to note that the triangle "dots on edge" are clipped, and - of course - there's no triangle with "dots outside," though that's not a deal-breaker by any means, and is due to the necessity of the ways of creating triangles with HTML/CSS.

Comment: @DavidThomas I considered not including the triangle attempt since the dots were clipped off. However, I decided this was a proof-of-concept approach and could possibly inspire an improvement. I was down to the buzzer to submit this late-night answer for the bounty and will make modifications going forward as I learn and/or see what I overlooked. Again, this answer would not have been possible without the info gleaned from Salman A's answer. I would give him half of the bounty if I were able to.

Comment: There is a formula for maximum rectangle inside triangle btw.

Answer (score 1):

first why the dots inside the circle is outside?

your point is a background image, its height is 100%, and its width is 30%, so it actually looks like this：[image]

so when add css with `.oval` with `border-radius: 50%`, the oval div change to  circle. But the dot will not follow the change, stay the same. And dot will look like outside circle.

If you want to make them closer together vertically, you can change the `before` and `after` `background-size: 40px 40px`, or you can set left and right to make them closer horizontally.
[image]

Also you can set the `.bolt:before, .bolt:after` `width` lager like 50% to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution can be less complicated and involve less HTML & CSS.

Adjust the dots' vertical proximity to each other by declaring a `height` percentage value for the pseudo-elements.

Adjust the dots' proximity to the shape edge by declaring a `top` percentage value (half of the remaining height.)

If `height: 60%`, then `top: 20%`. You may want to give the unique shapes their own height and top values.

```css
.shape {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
}

.oval {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.shape:before,
.shape:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 60%;
  width: 30%;
  top: 20%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center, red 5px, transparent 5px), radial-gradient(circle at center, black 5px, transparent 5px);
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-position: top center, bottom center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.shape:after {
  right: 0;
}

.shape.rectangle:before,
.shape.rectangle:after {
  height: 90%;
  top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div id="rectangle" class="shape"></div>
<hr>
<div id="oval" class="shape oval"></div>
<hr>
Position for rectangle shape
<div id="shape-rectangle" class="shape rectangle"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `border-radius` rounds the corners of an element's outer border edge, but does not affect the area it takes on DOM. When you apply `border-radius` it will change the position of `border` and `background` but not the content and area taken by element.

As you have given `boder-radius: 50%`, it start rounding corners from center, hence the children at the edge goes of the circle.

To make circle inside the oval, you can update the `background-position` of `:before` and `after`

```
.oval .bolt:before,
.oval .bolt:after {
      background-position: top 25% center, bottom 25% center;
 }
```

Complete Example :

```css
.rectangle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
}


.oval {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.bolt:before,
.bolt:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  top: 0px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center, red 5px, transparent 5px), radial-gradient(circle at center, black 5px, transparent 5px);
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-position: top center, bottom center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.bolt:before {
  left: 0px;
}

.bolt:after {
  right: 0px;
}

.oval .bolt:before,
.oval .bolt:after {
  background-position: top 25% center, bottom 25% center;
}
```

```html
<div id="rectangle" class="rectangle">
  <div>
    <div class="bolt">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div>
  <div id="oval" class="oval">
    <div class="bolt">

    </div>
  </div>
```